# How do you treat the data if the select data is large amount at the time of registration and edit in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

My\ConductBundle\Entity\Conduct:

```
// ...

manyToOne:
    model:
        targetEntity: My\ModelBundle\Entity\Model
        inversedBy  : conducts
        joinColumn  :
            name                : model
            referencedColumnName: id
```

My\ModelBundle\Entity\Model:

```
// ...

oneToMany:
    conducts:
        targetEntity: My\ConductBundle\Entity\Conduct
        mappedBy    : model
        cascade     : ["persist", "remove"]
```

My\ConductBundle\Form\Type

```
class ConductType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

    $builder->add('model', 'entity', array(
        'class'         => 'My\ModelBundle\Entity\Model',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('m')->where('m.disabled = 0')->orderBy('m.name', 'ASC');
        },
        'property'      => 'name',
        'empty_value'   => '- choose an model option -',
        'required'      => false,
    ));
```

My\ConductBundle\Resources\views\registerForm.html.twig:

```
<ul data-prototype="
        // ...
        <div class='model'>
            {{ form_widget(form.conducts.vars.prototype.model) | e }}
        </div>
        // ... ">
    {% for conduct in form.conducts %}
        <li>
            // ...
            // ... form error fields
            // ... conduct fields

            <div class='model'>
                {{ form_widget(conduct.model) }}
            </div>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<button name='conduct-field-add-button'></button>
```

It works so far.

But it is possible that the data will be a large amount
because the data ('model' in this condition) can be registered by any user.

It is possible to be one million records or more.
So I have to consider to solution.

---

### one step:

When there are few characters for search and there is data in large amount, I am surmising that processing becomes heavy. I want to avoid the way that is likely to be heavy process.

So I want to avoid this autocomplete solution.

---

### two step:

I tried to other way that render trigger button for search models.
By clicking the trigger button, a dialog to select the model will be displayed.
And it will set the value of hidden field when select the model (id).

```
    $builder->add('model', 'hidden', array(
        'property_path' => 'model.id',
    ));

    <input type='hidden' name='my_conduct_form_type[conducts][0][model]' value='5' />
```

However, in this case, I do not have the ability to combine data and form-type eventually.
It will be error.

```
    Neither the property 'id' nor one of the methods 'setId()', '__set()' or '__call()' exist
     and have public access in class 'My\ModelBundle\Entity\Model'. (500 Internal Server Error)
```

How do you treat the data if the select data is large amount at the time of registration and edit?

Comment: Have you tried using `select2` and loading remote data?

Comment: When there are few characters for search and there is data in large amount, I am surmising that processing becomes heavy. I want to avoid the way that is likely to be heavy process.　I would like to solve by a method like the second. For that purpose, I have to set a value dynamically in Javascript. Is such a thing possible?　The method of setting only ID to the value of the field was useless.